# What does the levels argument in the contourf mean?

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

This question is about the matploblib contourf function.
(https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf.html)

The documentation for the function describes the levels argument as

> levels : int or array-like, optional
>
> If array-like, draw contour lines at the specified levels. The values must be in increasing order.

My question is what do these levels of contour mean? Are they referring to the number density of points in the x-y plane?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line):

> A contour line (also isoline, isopleth, or isarithm) of a function of two variables is a curve along which the function has a constant value, so that the curve joins points of equal value.

So if you have a function `f(x,y)` a contour at level `a` is a line through the points where `f(x,y) == a`. You can provide several levels `a1, a2, a3, ...` to obtain several contour lines, one at `f(x,y) == a1`, one at `f(x,y) == a2`, etc..

Specify `levels` in [`.contour`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.contour) or [`.contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html)

In the matplotlib syntax,

```
plt.contour(x, y, f(x,y), levels=[a1, a2, a3])
```